# When I click on the menu li, menu not hidden (jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'M trying to create a menu hamburger-menu. I have a problem, if it clicks in li, the menu does not hidden

```
<nav  class="navbar__nav">
  <ul id="nav" class="navbar__nav--list">
    <li class="toggle">
      <div class="bar1"></div><div class="bar2"></div><div class="bar3"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__nav--list--item">
      <a href="#1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__nav--list--item">
      <a href="#2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__nav--list--item">
      <a href="#3">3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And js code

```
  $('.toggle').click(function(){
    $('#nav').toggleClass('open');
    $('.container').toggleClass('menu-open');
  });

   $('#nav li').click(function(){
    $('#nav').removeClass('open');
    $('.container').removeClass('menu-open');
  });
```

Comment: You can use `addEventListener("click", function()` and if toggleClass('open') remove this on same function.

Comment: The `.toggle` element matches both event handlers.  So when you click toggle, it is going to run both of those handlers, and they are going to step on each other.

Comment: Try changing the second selector to be `#nav li:not(.toggle)`

Comment: I tried to create the CSS as you have not provided that.. I have updated Javascript.. Let me know if it works! https://jsfiddle.net/uwo2ykLg/14/

Comment: If you want menu close on options click then https://jsfiddle.net/uwo2ykLg/15/  will help you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use toggleclass(); for opening the menu, you should use the same for closing.
Also you could just use toggle(); without the nedd of a specific class to hide or show the menu:

```
  $('.toggle').click(function(){
        $('#nav, .container').toggle();  
      });

       $('#nav li').click(function(){
         $('#nav, .container').toggle();
      });
```

there is more the one way to do that. Is there any css styling in order to need the class for menu open?